# Subquery SQL DB2

Tags: sql, subconsultas, db2

Estoy tratando de hacer un subquery (en una columna en particular) dentro del query base. El codigo es el siguiente.

```
select
z.po_id,
max(SELECT etcdc.ship_evnt_tms from COVINFOS.SHIPMENT_EVENT etcdc where 
etcdc.SHIP_EVNT_CD = '9P' and etcdc.ship_id=scdc.ship_id
order by etcdc.updt_job_tms, desc fetch first row only) as 
LLP_estimated_delivery_cdc
from covinfos.ibm_plant_order z
left join COVINFOS.IPO_LINE_TO_CASE A ON z.po_id = a.po_id
left JOIN COVINFOS.SHIPMENT scdc ON (A.SHIP_ID = scdc.SHIP_ID AND 
A.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE = scdc.SHIP_TO_LOC_CODE and scdc.loc_type = 'CDC')
group by z.po_id
```

Parece que hay algun tipo de error de sintaxis basado en el mensaje de error que sale cuando intento correr la consulta.

```
BIC00004. DAL01008. An error occurred while accessing the database.
ILLEGAL SYMBOL ".". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: , ). SQLCODE=-104, 
SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.62.56; THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN A 
PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=3.62.56
```

Sin embargo, a simple vista o por lo menos, mi vista, no hay error alguno. Ademas, corriendo el subselect por separado, si corre.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una coma de mas en la quinta linea

```
order by etcdc.updt_job_tms, desc fetch first row only) as
```

Cambiala a

```
order by etcdc.updt_job_tms desc fetch first row only) as
```

Comment: Uh, gracias por el tip. Lamentablemente fue un typo cuando armaba el codigo. El mismo error persiste sin esa coma en el ORDER BY.